# sending ids to controller and saving..?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

```
<apex:commandlink action="{!removeline}" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) "   reRender="thePB" target="_top" > <img src="{!$Resource.Red_Cross}" alt="Remove" title="Remove" />
<apex:param name="deleteid" value="{!op.Id}" assignTo="{!deleteid}"/>
</apex:commandlink >
```

I have cross image in front of every record.on click of that i am sending id to the controller.but the problem is when i click on cross 2 records and then click on delete button only 1 record is deleted.Can anyone suggest me how to save ids(more than 1 record) in controller and delete records on delete click.I am learning salesforce

Comment: I am not too clear with the question, can you post your controller code here so I can have a look?
I am assuming what you need to do is - use a for loop, add the stuff to a list and do a DML on the list.<br> <br>
Post the code, so I could know what exactly is happening. Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at the [stackexchange site dedicated to Salesforce-related questions](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) if you haven't visited it already. There's an excellent answer by [Andrew Fawcett](http://stackexchange.com/users/1753185/andrew-fawcett) for similar problem (mass update while you have mass delete) that should get you started: ["Creating a custom list-view button that handles multi-record selection"](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4102/799)

Answer (score 0):

You can use with the actionFunction and send the ids ​​by javaScript 
Something like

```
<script>  
 function removelines(){     
   var deleteIds = ....;
   removeline(deleteIds )
</script> 
<input type="button" class="btn" onClick="onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?'))"/>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!removeline}" name="removeline">
   <apex:param name="deleteIds" assignTo="{!deleteIds}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```